# How to scope Search to the current module only

Tags: coq

New to Coq, working through Software Foundations. Just discovered the `Search` command, but it will match *anything* in the current environment, whereas I really just want to search what things I've proven in the current module (i.e. not anything that's been imported). Something like `Search plus inside ..` (where '.' would mean "current module only").
I *could* just exclude every other module, but that's painful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown by the [reference manual documentation](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.Search), there is no variant of `Search` doing exactly what you ask.

However, here are 3 approaches that you can follow to address this use case—*search what things were proven in the current module*:

1. First, assuming you are developing material in an explicit `module`, you can temporarily close this module (i.e., `End module.`) and use `Search "…" inside module.`
   Full example:

   ```
   Module module.
   (* … *) Definition natty := 21. (* … *)

   End module. Search "nat" inside module.
   ```
2. If you don't use interactives modules, you can still [blacklist](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:table.Search-Blacklist) the identifiers that appear in the standard library (or other libraries) by specifying a common identifier (e.g., `Coq.`)
   Full example:

   ```
   Definition natty := 21. (* … *)

   Add Search Blacklist "Coq.". Search "nat".
   ```
3. Finally if you are not interested in a fine-grained search of patterns/types, but would just want to *print what things were defined/proven in the current module*, you can use [this command](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.Print-All):

   ```
   Definition natty := 21. (* … *)

   Print All.
   ```